# Google Cloud Storage - Python Client - Get Link URL of a blob

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

The Link URL at the Object details in the GoogleCloudStorage browser follows the template:

`https://storage.cloud.google.com/<project_name>/<file_name>?authuser=0&organizationId=<org_id>`

I'm trying to get the exact same link using the python package [google-cloud-storage](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/1.26.0/index.html). Diving into the blob properties I've found the followings (none of which are exactly what I need):

- self_link: `https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/<project_name>/o/<file_name>`
- media_link: `https://storage.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/<project_name>/o/<file_name>?generation=<gen_id>&alt=media`

**Note:** If I replace `storage.googleapis.com` with `storage.cloud.google.com` at the `media_link` I get to download the file as I expect (getting asked for a valid Google Account with the required permissions).

Is there any way to get the link directly from the blob object?

Answer (score 1):

Here the pattern:

`https://storage.googleapis.com/<BUCJET_NAME>/path/to/file`

For example, for a bucket `my_bucket` and a file stored in this path `folder_save/2020-01-01/backup.zip`, you have this url `https://storage.googleapis.com/my_bucket/folder_save/2020-01-01/backup.zip`

Comment: That's not exactly what I need. If I copy-paste into my browser a valid URL following your pattern, I would get an 'Access denied for Anonymous caller'.
Btw, I know I can compose a valid URL manually but the key point of my question is if I can extract it directly from a blob object (this would avoid issues if google change their base domain for google storage files in the future).

Comment: You mean that the files aren't reachable publicly?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best approach is manually generate the URL that you need by replacing the domain of the URL.

In [client library source](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/_modules/google/cloud/storage/blob.html#Blob) I couldn’t find any reference to a method/property in the blob class that uses the domain “storage.cloud.google.com”

even using the [public url](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/blobs.html#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob.public_url) property the result is the URL that points to googleapis